# Creating three dimensional Array with arbitrary type and map in Scala

Tags: java, scala, scala-collections, type-theory

When we have an Array of arbitrary type `X` in Scala and we try to do a double nest to each of its values using `map` (that is, turning `[1,2,3]` into `[[[1]],[[2]],[[3]]]`), we get a `java.lang.ArrayStoreException`. Code below is a minimal failing example:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def doubleNest[X: ClassTag](values: Array[X]): Array[Array[Array[X]]] = {
  values map { value =>
    Array(Array(value))
  }
}

doubleNest(Array(1,2,3))
```

What is more, error seems to arise when turning `[[1],[2],[3]]` into `[[[1]],[[2]],[[3]]]`. Code below is a minimal failing example (error happens in the second `map`):

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def doubleNest[X: ClassTag](array: Array[X]): Array[Array[Array[X]]] = {
  val nested = array map { value =>
    Array(value)
  }

  nested map { arr =>
    Array(arr)
  }
}

doubleNest(Array(1,2,3))
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Scala doesn't like making nested generic arrays directly. Even this fails:

```
def foo[T: ClassTag](t: T) = Array(Array(t))
foo(1) // java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [[I
```

(In this case, it's probably because `ClassTag` looks at the erased class, so `Array.apply` does the same, and it creates an `Array[Array[Object]]` instead of `Array[Array[T]]`.)

It also appears that `ClassTag` has the methods [`wrap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/reflect/ClassTag.html#wrap:scala.reflect.ClassTag[Array[T]]) and [newArray](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/reflect/ClassTag.html#newArray(len:Int):Array[T]) for this purpose. So, you can use some ugliness involving `implicitly[ClassTag[X]].wrap.wrap.newArray(array.length)` to get the job done, or you can do this, which seems to work by never directly asking it to create a nested array:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def nest[C: ClassTag](arr: Array[C]) = arr.map(Array(_))

def doubleNest[X: ClassTag](array: Array[X]): Array[Array[Array[X]]] =
  nest(nest(array))
```